# How to include the math library in MS-VS 2005 compiler project settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, math.h, libm

I am trying to build a C program which was originally built on Linux with gcc -lm ... option, which uses the math library while linking the code.  How can use the same in project settings of a Visual Studio 2005 compiler, on Win32 environment?

EDIT: Basically the original Linux code includes math.h and uses gcc -lm to link the math library.  But when I use this in Windows, I get a compilation error: `NAN :- undeclared identifier`.

I am looking to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ 2005 does not contain a definition for `NAN`. You can define it like this:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #ifndef NAN
        static const unsigned long __nan[2] = {0xffffffff, 0x7fffffff};
        #define NAN (*(const float *) __nan)
    #endif
#endif
```

(I got the code from [this blog post by Tom Distler](http://tdistler.com/2011/03/24/how-to-define-nan-not-a-number-on-windows). Thanks Tom.)