# How to include the math library in MS-VS 2005 compiler project settings?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to build a C code which originally is built on linux with 
`gcc -lm` ... option, which uses the math library while linking the code. How do I use the same in project settings of a Visual Studio 2005 compiler, on Win32 environment, to link the math library. Will just saying

```
#include "math.h"
```

be enough or i need to give math library as a dependency in the VS-2005 project settings, If yes then what is the setting for that?

Basic problem is when in my windows build, I include math.h but I get a compilation error:  nanf():- identifier not found

I am looking to resolve this.

thank you,

-AD

Comment: might get better responses on stackoverflow

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399641/how-to-include-the-math-library-in-ms-vs-2005-compiler-project-settings by the same author.

Comment: got it...i was thinking post in the appropriate place and DELETE XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include "math.h"` works fine on VS2005.

See [Floating-Point Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0ybw9fy%28VS.80%29.aspx).